# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS SDL2 wl_proxy_marshal_flags error

Tags: nvidia, gcc, sdl

I'm a beginner at using Linux, so I'm following a couple of forum threads I've read so far.

I'm trying to compile a C++ program using `g++` version `11.3.1`, where I have installed SDL2 using the command `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev` and am using the recommended proprietary driver `nvidia-driver-525` for my nvidia gtx 1060 graphics card. When I echo `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, it says `x11`.

However, when I compile the program using the link arguments `-lSDL2`, it gives me the following compile error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_flags'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I compile the program with the link arguments: `-lSDL2 -lwayland-egl -lwayland-client -lwayland-cursor`, it compiles successfully. But then when I try to run the program, it gives me this error:

```
./bin/main.exe: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdecor-0.so.0: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but I wonder if because [Wayland is the default for Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.ghacks.net/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-with-gnome-42-and-wayland-as-the-default/), the SDL2 library is also built with `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland` and you need to set `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11` explicitly in your environment if that's what you're using? See [How do I choose a specific video driver?](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/FAQUsingSDL)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried compiling and running with `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11` prepended but to no avail. I read something about how SDL2 released a version that defaulted to wayland, but later on reverted that decision due to issues with nvidia and such. Maybe I have the wrong SDL2 version installed?

Comment: Did you compile and link from scratch (i.e. remove any intermediate .o files) when you did that?

Comment: @steeldriver I've tried it both ways already (with and without .o files), and they produced the same result.